# Firestore SecurityRules get () issue

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to write a security rule for firestore DB and I'm having trouble for some reason. Does the syntax in the following code look wrong to anyone?

```
match /posts/{postType} {
  allow read: if true;
  allow write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/posts/$(postType)).data.creator_id == 
                  request.auth.uid;
}
```

I attached a screenshot of the path and the data structure. The problem I am getting is "get" is returning null.

Data & Path:
[image: Data & Path]

error:
[image: error]

Comment: What specifically goes wrong when you try to use these rules?

Comment: Security rules by themselves don't mean anything without also seeing the code that performs the query and the actual document data.  Please edit the question to show the code with the query and the database data that isn't working the way you expect.  There should be enough information in the question so that anyone can reproduce the issue.

Comment: My apologies I just edited the question to show the data and error. I'm using the rules simulator for the query.

Answer (score 1):

You must change the rule.

Instead of:

```
allow write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/posts/$(postType)).data.creator_id == request.auth.uid;
```

You must write:

```
allow write: resource.data.creator_id == request.auth.uid;
```

Comment: resource is coming back null for me? The path I am giving it is /posts/{postType}. Let's say I wanted to allow them to write to a sub-collection of the postsType if /posts/{postType} equals request.auth.uid? I'm assuming once I can do the first the sub-collection should just require proper paths. I'm just not sure how to use the {postType} variable.

Comment: Okay. The screenshots you have added, I can see a mistake while working with the rules playground. In the rules playground, they had asked you the location for that you have entered `/posts/{postType}`, in the place `{postType}` you must replace it with the documentID which is already there in your database. eg: `efsfsfesfesfefs` is my documentID, then in location it must be `/posts/efsfsfesfesfefs`.

Answer (score 0):

`request.resource.data.creator_id == request.auth.uid` was the solution!

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the simulator correctly.  When asked to enter the path of the document to get, you must provide a path to an **actual** document.  Do not type the wildcard from the match.  The rules will determine the actual value of the wildcard at the time the rule is evaluated.  If you enter "/posts/{postType}", you are telling it to literally load a document with the ID "{postType}", which doesn't exist.